# Stochastic Differential Equations for Trigonometric functions

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Give the Stochastic Differential Equations for $X_t = \cos B_t$ and $Y_t = \sin B_t$, where $B_t$ is the standard Brownian Motion.

I have used the following Ito formula:

$$dg(t,B_t) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(t, B_t)\,dt + \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(t, B_t)\,dB_t + \frac12\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial x^2}(t, B_t)\,dt$$
where
$g(t, B_t) = \cos B_t$ and $g(t, B_t) = \sin(t, B_t)$ for $X_t$ and $Y_t$ respectively.

This results in:

$$dX_t = -\frac12\cos B_t\,dt - \sin B_t\,dB_t\,,$$

$$dY_t = -\frac12\sin B_\,dt + \cos B_t\,dB_t\,.$$

But I wasn't sure if I was missing anything.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense [yet]. What is an SDE? What is $B(t)$?

Comment: Hint: what are $dX$ and $dY\,?$

Comment: Hint: Ito's lemma.

Answer (score 0):

From
\begin{align}
X_t&=\cos B_t\,,&Y_t&=\sin B_t
\end{align}
you got by Ito's formula
\begin{align}
dX_t&=-\sin B_t\,dB_t-\frac12\cos B_t\,dt\,,&dY_t&=\cos B_t\,dB_t-\frac12\sin B_t\,dt
\end{align}
which can be written as a coupled SDE for $X$ and $Y\,,$
\begin{align}
dX_t&=-Y_t\,dB_t-\frac12X_t\,dt\,,&dY_t=X_t\,dB_t-\frac12Y_t\,dt\,,
\end{align}
or as two uncoupled SDEs
\begin{align}
dX_t&=-\sin(\arccos X_t)\,dB_t-\frac12X_t\,dt\,,&dY_t=\cos(\arcsin Y_t)\,dB_t-\frac12Y_t\,dt\,.
\end{align}